# Binance - 'Account has insufficient balance for requested action.'

Tags: binance

I wanted to trade ETH to USDT and immediately after that USDT to ICX.
The first trade was successful and the api respondet:

```
{
  "symbol":"ETHUSDT",
  "orderId":123456789,
  "orderListId":-1,
  "clientOrderId":"doesntmatter",
  "transactTime":1615045329697,
  "price":"0.00000000",
  "origQty":"0.01972000",
  "executedQty":"0.01972000",
  "cummulativeQuoteQty":"30.64152760",
  "status":"FILLED",
  "timeInForce":"GTC",
  "type":"MARKET",
  "side":"SELL",
  "fills":[
    {
      "price":"1553.83000000",
      "qty":"0.01972000",
      "commission":"0.00010318",
      "commissionAsset":"BNB",
      "tradeId":doesntmatter
    }
  ]
}
```

As said, immediately after getting the response i sent another order and wanted to trade the USDT i got from the first trade to get ICX. I used the following queryparams:

```
quantity=30.64000000&side=BUY&symbol=ICXUSDT&timestamp=1615045328975&type=MARKET&signature=doesntmatter
```

However, i got this answer from the api:

```
{"code": -2010, "msg": "Account has insufficient balance for requested action."}
```

Why was there insufficient balance on my account?
Does it need some arbitrary time i have to wait until i can trade my assets after receiving them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and solved it

> quantity=quantity*0.995

In order to calculate the trading fees and not to sell the entire quantity